# AWS Cognito userpool changed email address pointless validation code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-cognito

i have set up a user pool using option 2 ( [see docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html#user-pool-settings-aliases-settings-option-2) ) where i use the email address to sign in together with a password.

users are able to register and log in successfully.

users can successfully change the email address.

i then use this code to change the email address:

cognitoUser.updateAttributes(attributeList, function (err,
result) {....}

the confusion or problem is:

changing the email address automatically sends a validation code to the new email address. what do i need to do with this code as the email address is changed without validation and the user can use the new address to login without any problems.

is it necessary to validate the changed email address when the address seems to be automatically validated without using the validation code? if i don't have to use the validation code, is there any way of preventing it being sent to the user when they change the email address as they will probably be confused when they receive it seeing that the changed email address works?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Verification is needed when user will try to use forgot password. If email is not verified the code for reseting password will not be send.

You can prevent it from being sent from General settings > MFA and verifications under "Which attributes do you want to verify?"